# What does return View(model) means in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am new to ASP.NET MVC programming. I would want to know what does the return View(model) does.

```
    public ActionResult CreateProducts(ProductsModel model)
    {
        /// Some code here.            

        return View(model);
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Please read the articles below:

- [ASP.NET Core Documentation](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/)
- [Introduction to ASP.NET Core](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/intro.html)
- [Adding a view](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/tutorials/first-mvc-app/adding-view.html)
- [MVC Views](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/mvc/views/index.html)
- [Views Overview](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/mvc/views/overview.html)

Answer (score 1):

It will return View (html page) with **Name "CreateProducts"** and controller **pass ProductsModel data in "model"**, which will use to bind with render html.

Answer (score 1):

When you hit the URL, something like `http://blah-blah/Products/CreateProducts`, 
a controller(Product controller in this case) object is created and initialized.

This controller contains the action method `CreateProducts` which is called via the above url.

The controller's job is to bind the Model and the View and render it as HTML in the Browser.

This is precisely done by the `View(model)` method.

Hope it helps..